# Line under a text in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, underline

*I'm a beginner/learner with HTML & CSS.*

How can i put a line under some text?

I don't want to underline the text but I want to make something along the lines of this

[image]

How can i implement this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `<hr>` tag.

Here is a nice page with some example styling: https://css-tricks.com/examples/hrs/

If you wanted to make it only 80% of the containers width you could add some CSS as follows

```css
hr {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Comment: You can also do by using css property, border-bottom.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to control the size of the line, you can use CSS.

```css
hr {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-style: inset;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<h1>HTML</h1>
<p>HTML is a language for describing web pages.....</p>

<hr>

<h1>CSS</h1>
<p>CSS defines how to display HTML elements.....</p>
```

Another thing you can do is boarder-bottom

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p  {
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom: thick line #ff0000;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    width: 250px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is some text in a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use an `<hr></hr>` tag

Example code:

```html
    <body>
      <h1> Header</h1>
      <hr>
      <p> text under header </p>
    </body>
```

Comment: But I want to make it smaller then all the page

Comment: Check out w3schools they have a great page full of info about this sort of stuff... https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp

Comment: `<hr>` is a standalone tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `hr` tag and style it via CSS:

```css
.x {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
<hr class="x">
```

Comment: Thanks I will try so

Comment: It's not left-aligned in the other answer, i.e. not completely under the text

Answer (score 1):

That's a valid question, I know what you mean

```
span{
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```